# Mongodb mapreduce performance

Tags: multithreading, mongodb, performance

I have a mapreduce function that I use to prepare data for my web app to be used in realtime.

It works fine but it doesn't require my performance requirements.

My aim is (and I know that it's not meant to be this way) to perform it when the webapp user request for it (more or less in realtime).

I do use Mapreduce because the transformation of the data needs a lot of if/else conditions due to functional requirements.

My subset of initial data to be transformed is about 100k rich documents ( < 1kB ).
The result is stored in a collection (in Replace mode) that will be then used by the webapp.

The duration of processing now is about 6-9 seconds and the CPU and RAM usage are very low.
The acceptable waiting time for my users should be less than 5 seconds.

So, to benefit from the not used CPU, I tried to divide my initial input data into subsets and perform the mapreduce in each subset by a different thread (20k documents per thread).

For that I had to change the Replae mode to Merge mode to be able to collect the result into the same collection.

But it didn't help. It consumes more CPU but the total execution time is the more or less the same.
Setting "nonAtomic" to true in my mapReduce calls didn't help neither.

I read somewhere that there are (at least) 2 issues with running it this way :

- My threads are not running in parallel for the inserts as the insert locks the output collection.
- My threads are not running in parallel during processing because the js engine used by mongodb is not thread safe.

Are these points correct? And do you know any other better solutions?

PS: My mapreduce doesn't group data, it only tranforms it based on functional conditions (a lot of them). All emitted documents are unique (so reduce is always 0).

**EDIT:**
Here is an example:

My input objects are a products groups. ie:

```
{
_id : "1",
products : [
  {code : "P1", name : "P1", price : 22.1 ...., competitors : [{code : "c1", price : 22.2},{code : "c2", price : 21.9}]},
  {code : "P2", name : "P2", price : 22.1 ...., competitors : [{code : "c1", price : 22.2},{code : "c2", price : 21.9}]},
]
}
```

Users should be able to define dynamically functional groups based on some criterias applied to each product and define a pricing strategy for each one of them.

As a simple example of functional groupping, they could define 4 groups like this :

- Cheap Products (whose price is less than 20)
- Products that are sold by both competitors "C1" and "C2"
- Products that are sold only by the competitor "C3"
- Products that are sold by the competitor "C4" and is not in Promo
  ...

All these groups are defined based on properties of the Product object and because 1 product can possibly fit more than 1 group, the first encountred should be the used one (if it fits in the first group, it must not appear in any other one).

Once the groups criteria defined, users can define for each group a strategy to apply to calculate a new price for each product based on some conditions (also uses Product properties BUT ALSO other products properties on the same Array of the original input object).

The result is a collection of separate products with its functinal group, its new price and some other calculated stats and values.

Comment: *"I have a mapreduce function ..."* Considering that unless you actually have a specific reason for doing otherwise then 90% of what you think you need mapReduce for is actually achievable at far better performance with the aggregation framework instead. The historical restriction has been key traversal, but either redesign of schema or modern releases work around that. The best way to explain is "by example". Show some minmal data, show the expected result from that sample and show the current code used to get to that result.

Comment: ok. I'm going to add one

Comment: @Neil Please check the edit at the bottom